# 403 forbidden error in wamp after installing zend

Tags: wamp, wampserver, http-status-code-403

My WAMP server started giving `403 Forbidden` error after I installed Zend framework. Before that everything was working ok.

I have allready edited:

```
#onlineoffline tag - don't remove   
Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
#onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Order allow, deny
Allow from all 
and put the server online
```

Comment: Is your entire wamp server giving a 403 on all sites or is your new site, where you just setup ZF, giving a 403?

Comment: In that case it has little to do with Zend Framework. Possible wrong document root configured in your Wamp config files. Could you provide us with details of your vhost config, actual directory structure etc? Also take a look at the search results, maybe your solution is in there: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wamp+403

Answer (score 0):

if I remember correctly at least one of the Zend installs comes with an Apache and MySQL which it installs as well as the framework.

Are you sure you have not got `wampapache` the WAMP apache service name, and `Apache` the standard apache service name both running?

EDIT

To view services:

Press windows key + R
enter `services.msc` into the dialog that launches.

Comment: i don't have any idea about that how to check? and i have tried in linux also there also i am unable to bind multiple hosts.every time i open zend server localhost opens up.